# Fetch values between two dates - MariaDB version: 10.1.37

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to fetch values between two dates, specifically 24hrs

```
SELECT * 
FROM `transactions` 
WHERE accnum = '1534610376' 
    AND tdate BETWEEN 20190311 AND 20190312
```

This query works fine but, i don't want it for a constant date, i have checked and seen many format but none seems to work. please help

Comment: "sql Server version: 10.1.37" - Sounds more like *MariaDB*. *SQL Server* is a different product. Please don't mix them up.

Comment: `SQLServer 10.1.7` or `MySQL` - They are not the same thing

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB yes it is

Comment: Are you running this code in PHP? Or directly on the database?

Comment: @RiggsFolly directly on the database (phpmyadmin)

Comment: What is the data type of `tdate`? And do you want records from today + yesterday?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel its a TIMESTAMP, and i want records from today alone, regardless how far spent the day is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "want records from today alone" - a simple way would be:

```
WHERE accnum = '1534610376' 
    AND DATE(tdate) = CURRENT_DATE()
```

However - To utilize an index, a column should not be wrapped into a function. So an efficient way would be

```
WHERE accnum = '1534610376' 
    AND tdate >= CURRENT_DATE()
    AND tdate <  CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

A good index for this query would be `INDEX(accnum, tdate)`.

Comment: Then, the optimal index would be `INDEX(accnum, tdate)`.

Comment: Right, @Rick - Included that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put your date between quots like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `transactions` 
WHERE accnum = '1534610376' 
    AND tdate BETWEEN '20190311' AND '20190312'
```

After, you can define a user defined function like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION BetweenDate(@toCompare VARCHAR(30), @rightDate DATE, @leftDate DATE)  
RETURNS TABLE
AS   
BEGIN  
    RETURN (
        SELECT *
        FROM transactions
        WHERE accum = @toCompare AND tdate BETWEEN @rightDATE AND @leftDate
    )
END;
```

Comment: the accnum is not a constant either its the active $session, i'm just testing it manually on phpmyadmin

Comment: So you can delete the @toCompare parameter and its ok

Comment: The quotes won't make any difference.  However, the normal way of specifying a date does need to be quoted:  `'2019-03-11'`.